# Create a service to change the username on screen when logging in using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on a node.js web application using angularjs for client side.

Basically when a user logs in i need to store their username and bind this to an element on the screen.

Rather than store in a session is there another way to store the information.

I have a template page which has the element displayed in there:

```
<div class="header">
<h3 class="text-muted">This is a template</h3>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Username here<b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Do i need to create a controller method for the template page which will call a service within my app.js file that will get the username?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Approach

I recommend to use a Factory as an [AngularJS Service](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services) for this. You could request the User information from an API and store it as an JSON object in the Factory. In your controller you can load your Factory and get the desired information like the username.

As every AngularJS service is a Singleton you can be sure that there is always just one instance with your User information.

---

### Code

**Service (Factory):**

```
app.factory('UserService',
  function($http) {
    // Here you can call a RESTful API resource,
    // store a JSON object in the application scope
    // and return it by this service to any controller.

    return {
      getUsername: function() {
        return "tjhack"
      }
    };
  });
```

**Controller:**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, UserService) {
  $scope.username = UserService.getUsername();
});
```

---

### Example

http://plnkr.co/edit/wma66tx6FefzrjzprwUN?p=preview

Comment: in regards to the api how will the api know which user is logged in? I am using passport js if that helps

Comment: Do you authenticate your api with user credentials? You could just return an echo like user JSON object which confirms that the user who tried to authenticate at your API entry point really is the user.

Comment: Yup i use username and password using the local strategy for passportjs. But in regards to getting the username and password would i need to store the id in the session and pass that to the user api which will return the json of the logged in user?

Comment: I don't know passportjs' local strategy. I think you should open a new question for that as it is not really related to your initial AngularJS question. Basically I would do the following steps 1. authenticate user by username/password 2. return the user's data and a token as a JSON Object 3. display the user data from the JSON Object 4. request further resources with the token you've got 5. and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Check this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=62RvRQuMVyg from Google Double Click team how they approached various various challenges building Angular App. At the very beginning they explain how they send user information from server and store it Angular.

Short summary: include user details as JSON payload to HTML document itself, then use service to store and access this data.